# Бот на php, которому всеравно, что напишет пользователь

Tags: php, api

Cтолкнулся с таким вопросом, нужно сделать конструктор ботов( это не относится к теме вопроса ).Начну с того , что ботам все равно что вы им напишите, есть заготовленный сценарий и даже если человек напишет не то что нужно бот перейдет к другому сообщению для пользователя и так для всех сообщений.  Как такое реализовать ?

Comment: По сути, вы спрашиваете как реализовать бота...

Comment: слишком обширный вопрос. Оперируйте своими возможностями и знаниями. Все зависит только от вас...напишите вы какую-нибудь программу с простым алгоритмом или создадите нейронную сеть. Решений слишком много дабы дать однозначный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $text = $_POST['pass'];

  if (strpos($text, 'привет') !== false) {
    $yes='Привет';
}
echo $yes;
```